# Character Limit On ConcatRelated() Function

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, concatenation

I have been using Allen Browne's `ConcatRelated()` function but am realizing with larger data sets the data is incomplete.

Does this function have a character limit, and if it does - is there a different function /UDF that can achieve the same result?

This is the function: - and link back to original thread http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

```
Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
    strTable As String, _
    Optional strWhere As String, _
    Optional strOrderBy As String, _
    Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Generate a concatenated string of related records.
    'Return:    String variant, or Null if no matches.
    'Arguments: strField = name of field to get results from and concatenate.
    '           strTable = name of a table or query.
    '           strWhere = WHERE clause to choose the right values.
    '           strOrderBy = ORDER BY clause, for sorting the values.
    '           strSeparator = characters to use between the concatenated values.
    'Notes:     1. Use square brackets around field/table names with spaces or odd characters.
    '           2. strField can be a Multi-valued field (A2007 and later), but strOrderBy cannot.
    '           3. Nulls are omitted, zero-length strings (ZLSs) are returned as ZLSs.
    '           4. Returning more than 255 characters to a recordset triggers this Access bug:
    '               http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         'Related records
    Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset       'Multi-valued field recordset
    Dim strSql As String            'SQL statement
    Dim strOut As String            'Output string to concatenate to.
    Dim lngLen As Long              'Length of string.
    Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean    'Flag if strField is a multi-valued field.

    'Initialize to Null
    ConcatRelated = Null

    'Build SQL string, and get the records.
    strSql = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    If strOrderBy <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy
    End If
    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
    'Determine if the requested field is multi-valued (Type is above 100.)
    bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)

    'Loop through the matching records
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If bIsMultiValue Then
            'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
            Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
            Do While Not rsMV.EOF
                If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                    strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
                End If
                rsMV.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set rsMV = Nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    'Return the string without the trailing separator.
    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rsMV = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

**Edit**
I am using VBA and running an `Into` statement.  Would it work better if I generated the table first and then insert the data?

Current structure

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Select DISTINCT [ImportTable].DSFNum, 

ConcatRelated('[Item]','[ImportTable]','[DSFNum] =' & [DSFNum]) AS Item, 
ConcatRelated('[Count]','[ImportTable]','[DSFNum] =' & [DSFNum]) AS Count 
INTO [OneRowTable] 
FROM [ImportTable]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the relevant information can be found in the code for the `ConcatRelated` function:

> 4. Notes: Returning more than 255 characters to a recordset triggers this Access bug:
>      http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html

As can be found on that page, the problem is not the function, but the fact that a text field in Access can't contain that many characters, and can be fixed by using something like

```
SELECT ID, MuchText FROM StructureOnly 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, ConcatRelated(something, table, where) AS MuchText FROM LotsaText;
```

Where `MuchText` is a memo field

A workaround using VBA and recordsets:

```vb
Dim rsSelect As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsInsert As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsSelect = db.OpenRecordset ("Select DISTINCT [ImportTable].DSFNum FROM [ImportTable]")
Set rsInsert = db.OpenRecordset("OneRowTable")
Do While Not rsSelect.EOF
    rsInsert.AddNew
    rsInsert!DSFNum = rsSelect!DSFNum
    rsInsert!Item = ConcatRelated("[Item]","[ImportTable]","[DSFNum] =" & rsSelect!DSFNum)
    rsInsert!Count = ConcatRelated("[Count]","[ImportTable]","[DSFNum] =" & rsSelect!DSFNum)
    rsInsert.Update
    rsSelect.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: See my edit - should I create the table first as a memo field - then insert the data?  Would that resolve this 255 limit issue?

Comment: You've got another separate issue there. You can't do a `SELECT DISTINCT` with a memo field, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html. `DISTINCT` is equal to adding all fields to a `GROUP BY` clause, and hence, it won't work. Without removing the `DISTINCT`, the `UNION` workaround won't work. I would rewrite your whole code to work with recordsets, and not use a `SELECT INTO`, because working around it will be difficult.

Comment: Do you have any helpful links on working with recordsets?

Comment: Nope, but I have enough information to write the solution, though. See the answer. You need to create the table first.