# Use Variable With RecordSet

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to iterate a table by using recordset.  This is the syntax that I have, but my issue is that if I do a Debug.Print for rsInsert!StoreNumber it is always blank!  Now if I do a Debug.Print for storenumfield it contains a value.  What would be the proper way to use a variable in the Insert statement like below?

```
Dim rsSelect As DAO.Recordset, rsInsert As DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsSelect = db.OpenRecordset("Select DISTINCT [_SpreadsheetImport]." & storenumfield & " FROM [_SpreadsheetImport]")
Set rsInsert = db.OpenRecordset("NewTable")
Do While Not rsSelect.EOF
    rsInsert.AddNew
    rsInsert!StoreNumber = rsSelect!& storenumfield
    rsInsert![VID] = ConcatRelated("[VID]", "[_SpreadsheetImport]", "[snF] =" & rsSelect!snF)
    rsInsert.Update
    rsSelect.MoveNext
Loop
```

Original syntax written by @Erik von Asmuth 
-> link to profile

https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth

-> with full post here

[Character Limit On ConcatRelated() Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036174/character-limit-on-concatrelated-function)

Comment: This is the way I would do this suppose 
I have a table in which employee id's and some other fields are stored as. To read emp_id I would use 

rs!Emp_Id.your using wrong syntax "rsSelect!& storenumfield"

Comment: @singhm0077 - what happens is a user inputs which column holds the Store Number- then I use VBA to capture the field store numberand store it in a variable.  So for example the field name could be StoreNum, StoreNumber, Store_Number etc.  I just want to access the value stored in the variable

Comment: use  rs!StoreNum to read value

Comment: Change "rsInsert!StoreNumber = rsSelect!& storenumfield"  to >>> rsInsert!StoreNumber = rsSelect.Fields(" & chr(34) & 1 &  chr(34) & ")"

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - where does the 1 come from?

Comment: @singhm0077 - I no longer need to use the rsInsert?

Comment: UGH! My bad the '1' was supposed to be 'storenumfield'  thus rsInsert!StoreNumber = rsSelect.Fields(" & chr(34) & storenumfield & chr(34) & ")"

Comment: dim Vtemp as variant

 Vtemp  = rsSelect!storenumfield this  will work

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn 0> that got it thank you

Comment: That looks oddly similar to the code I just posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036174/character-limit-on-concatrelated-function) for another user (even variable names and all). That's allowed, but technically attribution is required if you're adapting code from another Stack Overflow post.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth -> Yes I did locate the code from the post you linked to.  Not sure what you mean by attribution?  But if I need to edit my post for any reason I am more than happy to.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh read the [Attribution Required blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). Content on Stack Overflow is intellectual property of the one who wrote it, but freely available, as long as you attribute it to that person. You should do so not only here, but also in your work (using a code comment for example)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - do I need to link to the post or is calling you out in my OP sufficient?  And thank you for the link, I was unaware of that

Comment: The blog by Jeff Atwood (one of the creators of Stack Overflow) specifies that you need a link to the original answer, my name and a link to my profile. I always like it if you at least provide a link to the original answer, so people can see how I wrote it, and don't care about the rest.

Comment: I added your name & a link to the original post, I will add in a link to your profile as well.  Thank you for pointing this out to me.