# MSACCESS: truncated query with Distinct

Tags: ms-access

Currently, running the code down below. However as the field DDMProcess_Merged is a long text, when I use distinct, the input gets cut off. Before using distinct, the input does not get truncated. However, there will be repeats of the records which I do not want. To better visualise the issue, the tables are below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DD_MASB.ProcessM_ID, 
     CONCATRELATED("[DDM]","DD_MASB","ProcessM_ID = " & [ProcessM_ID]) AS DDMASB_Merged, 
     CONCATRELATED("[DDM_Process]","DD_MASB","ProcessM_ID =" & [ProcessM_ID]) AS DDMProcess_Merged

FROM DD_MASB;
```

Is there any solution to solve this?

Original Table query (without distinct):

| ProcessM_ID | DDMASB_Merged | DDMProcess_Merged |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | z |
| 1 | x | z |
| 1 | x | z |
| 2 | y | a |

Comment: This is by design and cannot be changed. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: @Andre thanks for the website, checked it before coming here. But don't seem to be able to fix it with what was mentioned with uniqueness. Unless my implementation is wrong that is

Comment: Then edit question to show that attempt. You need a dataset (table or query) where ProcessM_ID is already unique. Then use that table/query in a query that calls the ConcatRelated() function.

Comment: Or call function from textbox.

Comment: @June7 the ProcessM_ID is not exactly unique, in the sense that this is a one to many relationship. The ProcessM_ID relates to the DDM_ID (the id for this table). So meaning in the raw data table, there are many DDM_ID linking to a single ProcessM_ID. In using the ConcatRelated Function, it merges everything, however, duplicates results based on the number of DDM_IDs attached to a single ProcessM_ID.

Comment: Doesn't alter advice already given. ProcessM_ID is foreign key and DDM_ID is primary key? Use table with DDM_ID as source in a query to call the ConcatRelated function. The function still refers to table DD_MASB for pulling data with DDM_ID as parameter. `CONCATRELATED("[DDM_Process]","DD_MASB","ProcessM_ID =" & [DDM_ID])`

Comment: Yes, ProcessM_ID is the foreign key and DDM_ID is the primary key. Tried the code you attached, it ends up ignoring the ProcessM_ID. Exmaple: The record that is meant for ProcessM_ID.value =2, ends up ion ProcessM_ID.value =1 instead. The whole query is currently ```SELECT DD_MASB.ProcessM_ID, CONCATRELATED("[DDM]","DD_MASB","ProcessM_ID =" & [DDM_ID], CONCATRELATED("[DDM_Process]","DD_MASB","ProcessM_ID =" & [DDM_ID]) ) FROM DD_MASB;```

Comment: You can get around this by using VBA - see @ErikA answer on using a recordset to fill a table with the distinct results https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036333/2419128

Comment: I said use the table that has DDM_ID field. What table is that? `SELECT DDM_ID, ConcatRelated(...) FROM tablename ...`